# how to count different column values for a single Oracle ID and dispaly the result as a column

Tags: sql-server

how to count different column values for a single Oracle ID and dispaly the result as a column

```
        Oracle  | Status| other columns |   
        41      |  A   |
        52      |  W   |
        41      |  A   |
        52      |  W   |
        41      |  W   |
        __________________
        I need a resulting query that shows the count of distinct Status in every Oracle like this:

        Oracle | Total(A) | Total(W) |    
        41     |    2     |     1    |
        52     |    0     |     2    |
```

Comment: Please look it now. i need to count column oracle id and displays its status by counting SL,A,Resigned,AL

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to do.  What is the logic for assigning values for this other columns?  Are you looking for a select statement or an update?  Where is the status stored?

Comment: Dear, Please look on it. i think it will be clear

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to count values from rows and display the result in columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23218808/how-to-count-values-from-rows-and-display-the-result-in-columns)