# How to count values from rows and display the result in columns

Tags: sql-server

please help me

```
Oracle | Status| other columnns |   
41      |  A   |
52      |  W   |
41      |  A   |
52      |  W   |
41      |  W   |
__________________
```

I need a resulting query that shows the count of Status in every Oracle like this:

```
Oracle | Total(A) | Total(W) |    
41     |    2     |     1    |
52     |    0     |     2    |
```

---

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`with CTE AS 
( select oracle,status from TableName)
select * from CTE 
Pivot 
(count(status) for status in ([A],[W]) ) as pvt`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select oracle, count(distinct status) 
  from your_table
 group by oracle
```

You won't have the **exact same result** but you will have all the data you need to build that table.

You could also try some windows functions.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 ways to get that data:
1.

```
SELECT t1.oracle, ISNULL(Total_A, 0) As [Total (A)], ISNULL(Total_W,0) As [Total (W)]
FROM
(
SELECT oracle, count(status) As Total_A
FROM TableName
WHERE status = 'A'
GROUP BY oracle
) t1 INNER JOIN
(
SELECT oracle, count(status) As Total_W
FROM TableName
WHERE status = 'W'
GROUP BY oracle
) t2 ON(t1.oracle = t2.oracle)
```

This will give you the table you asked for, however, I will **not** recommend it as it is a terrible mess.

2.

```
SELECT oracle, status, COUNT(status)
FROM TableName
GROUP BY oracle, status
```

This will give you a table that you can then arrange in code to look like the table you requested in very little effort. Also, it is much cleaner and will be easy to handle a new status if introduced to the system.